# How to dichotomize categorical variables into a new variable with 1s and 0s but maintain NAs?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable within my data frame to encapsulate questions with two categorical answers. I would like to be able to convert these to 1s and 0s.

I've been using the `ifelse()` function but I feel like it inherently wants to convert `NA` values into 0s in my case. Adding the `na.rm=TRUE` argument onto the end gives me an error.

```
data$Knowledge=ifelse(data$Variable=="Yes",1,0, na.rm=TRUE)
```

> Error in ifelse(data$Sabe.qué.trata.la.Ley.No.26378..Convención.sobre.los.Derechos.de.las.personas.con.discapacidad..sobre.las.personas.Sordas.o.hipoacúsicas. ==  : 
>     unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: There is. `na.rm` argument in `ifelse`.  Probably you need `as.integer(data$Variable %in% "Yes")`

Comment: Do you mean "There is no `na.rm` argument ..." ? Can you post your comment as an answer? (Why bother with `%in%` when `==` will do here?)

Comment: @BenBolker yes, I meant it that way.   Sorry!   I was thinking that the OP's column have some `NA`, so `==` will return the `NA` or else have to make some adjustments with `is.na`

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse()` doesn't have an `na.rm` argument (in any case, you don't want to *remove* `NA` values, you want to pass them on in the result). A solution with explicit logic: nested `ifelse`

```
x <- c("Yes","No",NA)
ifelse(is.na(x),NA,ifelse(x=="Yes",1,0))
```

A more efficient solution based on coercion of logical values to integers (`TRUE` -> 1, `FALSE` -> 0, `NA` -> `NA`)

```
as.integer(x=="Yes")
```